# Change JTextPane text on boolean variable change

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a main class with two subclasses, one for the GUI initialisation and one for server creation and functionality. I have a boolean variable 'connected', which is true when a user is connected to the server and false when not. How would I be able to update the text of a JTextPane in the GUI subclass from the server subclass to say "client connected" when 'connected' is true and "no connection" when false?

main class:

```
public class serverMain {

    public static boolean allowConnections = false;
    public static boolean connected = false;
    public static boolean launchOnStart = false;
    public static boolean loop = true;

    public static int serverPort = 1234;
    public static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        serverGUI.gui();

        while (loop){

            if (allowConnections == true){
                serverCommands.commands();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("reject");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

gui class (irrelevant parts removed):

```
public class serverGUI extends serverMain {

    public static JTextPane txtConnectionMarker;

    public static void gui(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    serverGUI window = new serverGUI();
                    window.frmRemoteServer.setVisible(true);
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public serverGUI() {
        initialise();
    }

    public void initialise() {

        frmRemoteServer = new JFrame();
        frmRemoteServer.setBounds(100, 100, 720, 420);
        frmRemoteServer.setResizable(false);
        frmRemoteServer.setTitle("Remote Server");
        frmRemoteServer.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        frmRemoteServer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmRemoteServer.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JTextPane txtConnectionMarker = new JTextPane();
        txtConnectionMarker.setEditable(false);
        txtConnectionMarker.setBounds(548, 21, 149, 33);
        txtConnectionMarker.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI Light", Font.BOLD, 16));
        txtConnectionMarker.setBackground(SystemColor.menu);
        frmRemoteServer.getContentPane().add(txtConnectionMarker);

        if (connected == true){
            txtConnectionMarker.setText("Connected");
            txtConnectionMarker.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else {
            txtConnectionMarker.setText("No Connection");
            txtConnectionMarker.setForeground(Color.RED);
        }

        // obviously this will not update as connected changes

    }
}
```

server class (irrelevant parts removed):

```
public class serverCommands extends serverMain {

    public static void commands() {

        String input;

        try {

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);
            System.out.println("socket opened on port "+serverPort);

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            connected = true;

            // there's more to all parts but the given code
            // should be enough to get what I'm trying to do
            // basically once the user disconnects connected
            // will change back to false
```

Comment: `if (connected) { label.setText("Connected"); } else { label.setText("Client not connected) }` maybe (?)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Accessing the JTextPane instance? Setting the text at the right time? Appending to the JTextPane? Please be more specific, or else we can just guess. Ideally please also show what you've tried in a [mcve].

Comment: Model-View-Controller

Comment: @Frakcool probably the user is not able to access the component instance?

Comment: @SatoshiKouno OP asked *How would I be able to update the text of a JTextPane in the GUI subclass from the server subclass to say "client connected" when 'connected' is true and "no connection" when false?* that's what I "answered"... If he's not able to access it then maybe he should post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) don't you think so?

Comment: @LuxxMiner The issue is I am not sure how to change the text of the JTextPane from outside of the method that initialises the GUI objects. I guess I need some sort of actionlistener for the variable 'connected' changing to update the text (I know how to change the text just not as the boolean value changes) as it changes from false to true.

Comment: @KaiHulme *I am not sure how to change the text of the JTextPane from outside of the method that initialises the GUI objects* what about if you post a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to see it? As is, this question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sort of listener using a java interface where the implementation of the listener method is written in your subclass.

```
public interface ResultListener {
    public void setResult(boolean result);
}
```

Then the only thing you need is pass this interface as parameter where you initialize the server and call the listener method.

```
public class MyServer {

    private ResultListener listener;

    public MyServer(ResultListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener;
    } 

    public void doSomething() {

        // other stuff
        listener.setResult(true); // or false if connected or not

    } 

}
```

And finally:

```
public class MainClass implements ResultListener {

    public void init() {
        // your GUI and other logic

        MyServer server = new MyServer(this);
        server.doSomething();

    } 

    @Override
    public void setResult(boolean result) {

        if(result) {
            // do stuff
            label.setText("Connected!");
        } else {
            // do other stuff
            label.setText("Connection failed!");
        } 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Don't forget that the Swing is not Thread safe and any updates to the UI MUST be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread